# Word dictionary search using python recursion

Tags: python, search, recursion

I have to make a function:

```
    def allPaths(input,destination,num):
```

it input is a word in the dictionary, destination is also a word in the dictionary. num is the number of recursive calls you have to get from input to destination.

```
    def oneLetterDiff(word):
```

this returns all the words (list) in the dictionary that are off by one letter, in any of strings index. It has already been written and works.

How can I get allPaths to recursively search all OneLetterDiff(and the list it returns) the number of times specified in num? If the destination is found, it must return the words (aka. the path) it took to get to the destination.

current code:

```
    def wordPath(word, dest, times):
        path = []
        offOne = oneLetterDiff(word)


        if times > 0:
            if word == dest:
                path.append(word)
                return path

    return path
```

Thanks!

Lloyd

Comment: If you understand the basic idea of recursion, but can't think of how to get started: the base case is obviously when `input == destination`, in which case you can just return `num`. So, when that _isn't_ true, how can you reduce the problem to one or more calls where the difference between the words is smaller? (If you don't understand the basic idea of recursion, you need to go learn somewhere else; nobody can teach that in the form of an SO answer.)

Comment: current code has been added to post

Comment: OK, first, what should happens if `times == 0`?

Comment: And second, what should happen if `times > 0` but `word != dest`? This is where you need to reduce the problem to one or more calls to `wordPath`. Given `word`, `dest`, `times`, and `offOne`, what calls could you make to `wordPath` that would help?

Comment: if times == 0:
return path

Comment: This is where i'm really getting hung up:

wordPath(?, ?, times -1)

i need to decrement times, but how should I go about contructing the new call?

Comment: Think about this: What are all those values in `offOne` for?

Comment: does this require me to loop thru offOne calling wordPath(offOne[index],dest,times-1)? Am I on the righ track?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track. You just have to look at what result you get back from each of those calls, and what you can do with each result.

Comment: how do i return that, versus the path?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to write your base cases. You already know how to do this:

```
def wordPath(word, dest, times):
    if times == 0:
        return []

    if word == dest:
        return [word]
```

And you also know what recursive calls you want to make:

```
    offones = oneLetterDiff(word)
    for offone in offones:
        result = wordPath(offone, dest, times-1)
        ??? something with each result ???
    ??? something if you run out of results to try ???
```

So, you have to figure out what you want to do with `result`. The answer depends on what result you got back. It's going to be a path—a list of words. But you know that an empty list means failure, and a one-word list means the end of a path; you just need to figure out how to build from there.

If it returned an empty list, that means that there's no path through `offone`. But that doesn't mean there's no path through `word`; you'll only know that if you get to the end of the list, and *all* of them returned `[]`. So, continue on to the next loop in this case.

If it returned `[dest]` (which is also the same as `[offone]`, of course), that means that the path from `word` to `dest` is just `[word, dest]`. So, that's what you return.

What if it returned something else, like `[offone, <some other word>, dest]`, then you know that it succeeded. So, what's the path from `word` to `dest` in that case? That's what you return.

If you figure that out, you're pretty much done.